# Sticky table header doesnt work in angular materials mat-sidenav-container

Tags: css, angular, html-table, angular-material, sticky

Heyho,

I have some trouble with html/css tables and sticky headers when using angular material.

In my project I use angular materials sidenav with `<mat-sidenav-container>`, `<mat-sidenav>` and `<mat-sidenav-content>`. Inside `<mat-sidenav-container>` the sticky header of tables doesn't work.

I created a small project on github to easily reproduce the issue:
Repo: https://github.com/ManticSic/angular-material-sticky-table-issue
GH Pages: https://manticsic.github.io/angular-material-sticky-table-issue/

The table header is moved 64px downwards, instead of being fixed at y=64px when scrolling.

Do you have any idea how i can fix this?

Cheers and thx

---

**Notes**

- It would be okay, if the header is sticked/fixed to the top of the page, because only a table is displayed when I use this view where I need this. But I need proper columns with the correct width.
- I hope my problem can be fixed w/o JavaScript
- The solution has to work in the latest versions of firefox, chrome/chromium, safari and samsung mobile browser

---

**Not Working Solutions**

- `position:fixed` on app-table-header and removing `position:sticky` from cells:
  Not working, because the colum-width is not correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Removing/overriding overflow properties of mat-sidenav-container and mat-sidenav-content will fix the issue

Angular Material will auto generate mat-sidenav-content if its not set.

navigation.component.sass

```
mat-sidenav-container, mat-sidenav-content
  overflow: initial
```

thx to all who visited this question!

Answer (score 0):

Use position:fixed instead of sticky along with width:100% hope this will help.

for example:

```
app-table-header {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: fixed;
    top: 64px;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fafafa;
}
```

i have added same table background color for app-table-header so it will look better.

Comment: unfortunately not. If I add `position: fixed` to app-table-header and romiving `position:sticky` from app-table-cell is header is always at `y=64px` and the column with is not the same as the width of the body columns.